# Get index of Rows with checked boxes and convert to integer array

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagrid with data in the first few columns and a checkbox in the last column to the right.  The data columns have checkboxes that can only be selected (2) at a time indicating the input data.  When data is changed in the checked rows the remaining rows are updated with calculated output from the input data rows.  Depending on which (2) rows are checked a sequence for calculating the remaining rows is assigned.  I'm struggling with how to capture the (2) rows selected and assign a sequence to it.   There are (6) rows in total and any combination of (2) can be selected.  Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
    private void dgvParameters_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    //Get index of Rows with boxes checked in Column [5] and assign an integer array sequence
    //Ex: if Rows 1 & 3 are selected then int sequence = new int[6] {0,5,2,4,6};
    //Ex: if Rows 1 & 2 are slected then int sequence = new int[2] {0,3,7};

            for (int i = 0; i < sequence.Length; i++)
            {
                switch (sequence[i])
                {
                    case 0: 
                        //Do calculation for input from row 0 to update other rows
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        //Do calculation for input from row 1 to update other rows
                        break;
                    ...
                    case 7:
                        //Do calculation for input from row 7 to update other rows
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
    }
```

Here is some clarification on the int array portion:

```
//Formulas f() for calculation data values:
Row 1 = a = f(c,d)
Row 2 = b = f(a,d)
Row 3 = c = f(a,b)
Row 4 = d = f(b,c)

//EX: if Row 1 & 2 selected then use the values in these cells to solve for Row 3 & 4
//sequences have to be in a particular order to update the formulas correctly.
if Rows Selected = 1 & 2 then sequence = {3 ,4} //Calculate Rows 3 & 4 
if Rows Selected = 3 & 4 then sequence = {1, 2}
if Rows Selected = 1 & 4 then sequence = {2, 3}
```

Comment: Based on the last post, Instead of getting the `.Count()` of the checked cells, get their `OwningRow`. For example: `var rows = dgvParameters.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().SelectMany(r => r.Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCheckBoxCell>().Where(c => (bool)c.FormattedValue)).Select(c => c.OwningRow);`. I don't understand the `int` arrays part and how should they be created. So, take it from here and try. If you need to get row array instead of `IEnumerable`, append `.ToArray();` method.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I've added some clarification for the int array portion.  I will try your suggestion.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Also, might be useful to mention, after selecting the checked rows by the mentioned above query, you can query the non-checked rows by: `var otherRows = dgvParameters.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Except(rows);`.

Comment: I appended ".ToArray()" and used a "foreach (var item in rows) { listBox1.Items.Add(item);}" to view the rows selected.  The output is "DataGridViewRow { Index=1}" for row 1 for example.  How can I just get the row integer as output?

Comment: `foreach (var item in rows) listBox1.Items.Add(item.Index);`

Comment: How do I count the items in rows?
' for (rows.ToArray().Count() > 0) '

Comment: What items? Do you mean how many row in rows? If so, No need to call `.ToArray()`, call `var count = rows.Count();` instead. If you already have an array, don't call `Count` and get the `Length` property. `var count = SomeRowArray.Length;`. Have you resolved the problem? If not yet, you can add more details like what `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` are, cell values? Which ones? And when you say `b = f(a,d)`, would you say in other words `b = f(f(c,d), d)`?

Comment: I apologize if I confused the issue. All other issues were resolved.  I think I just need to obtain the length of the var rows = dgvParameters... array as you declared above and include error handling for an empty array.  I will assign an array based on the datagrid row number to be used in a loop to calculate cell values.  Ex: If var rows.Length = 2 then {if var rows.Index[1]=1 & Index[2] =2 then calculation sequence array for loop2={0,3,2}} etc...for different combinations of datagrid row numbers found. var count = rows. Count() works as you suggest.  Thank you.